# How to get date and time of uploaded firmware?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have some kind of smart home on multiple esp8266, and I periodically update code of their firmwares via Arduino OTA.
And sometimes I forget to upload actual code on them. For example, I don't remember, if I uploaded a new version of firmware to esp8266, that serves in toilet :) .

Each of Arduino esp8266 firmware is *.bin file, if I understood it correctly. Each of file has time of creation.
And question is - does esp8266 store date and time of firmware, uploaded via OTA (or update) and is there any Arduino program method to get that date and time?

Comment: Where in the ESP8266 datasheet does it say this information is stored?  Don't know?  Read it.  Does the Arduino open-source documentation cover this?  Read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Provided by compiler at compile time.
const char compile_date[] = __DATE__ " " __TIME__;

Serial.print("Compile timestamp: ");
Serial.println(compile_date);
```

Or add a Webserver endpoint that returns it, like http://device-ip/info

If you use an IDE like Visualcode you might be able to setup an auto build number define.

Personally I'm working on an ESP Manager.  A small wrapper you include in your sketch, which establishes your Wifi, broadcasts it's firmwareId and mac address.  A python server listens for these, compares them to a list of devices by mac and what firmware they should be running and if there is a missmatch, flashes them OTA.  You can see from it's logs what everything is running.

I have it working, but not checked in yet, PM me if interested, or maybe I'll comment back with a link later.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this idea. Currently, I use Arduino IDE to flash firmware to my ESPs. What is ESP Manager you are talking about? Is it https://github.com/sticilface/ESPmanager ?

Comment: I made my own.  This is an example of it's use.
https://gitlab.com/paulcam/home_heating/-/tree/master/esp8266/RadiatorSwitchS20/RadiatorSwitchS20/src
And the manager is just a prototype python server.
https://gitlab.com/paulcam/home_heating/-/tree/master/ESP_Manager

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function that returns the version and set the version each time before upload.
For example:
const String version = "3.51";
then return it to serial, html page dedicated, OTA Server Page method or mqtt.
I think there is no easy way like you are trying.